# how to restart game using ui button unity 4.6?

Tags: unity-game-engine, restart

I want that the player could play again when they're done playing.

The method works fine when I place it OnGUI(), but when I apply it to an UI button, the restart just hangs and the countdown timer isn't working at all.

```
public void playAgain(){
    Application.LoadLevel (Application.loadedLevelName);
    Character.score = 0;

    time.second = 30.0f;
}
```

Comment: retagged. you used 2 wrong tags. And you didn't ask the timer to restart (you just set the second)

Comment: @Raptor actually i just set the second, then in the time class i'm using StartCoroutine (timeStart ()) to animate the the timer. i used this tutorial as reference for timer animation
(https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtQ1ylRLZsA)

Comment: what does "the restart just stuck" mean? What exactly happens?

Comment: Are you sure this code is being called? Secondly, what is 'time'? Only static variables are preserved after calling LoadLevel takes effect. In that case although you set time after calling LoadLevel, that won't take effect right away so there maybe an issue here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you probably set the time.timeScale = 0 when the game ended, and you probably forgot to start it over on the start of the level.

Comment: You're right, i'm sorry i was careless. Thank you for your help